# What packages/programs should I install to get better graphics and performance on gaming?

Tags: software-recommendation, graphics, package-management, games, performance

So, I want to install some packages/programs to get better graphics and performance while playing a game on Ubuntu 11.10. What packages/programs you guys recommend to me?

Comment: Should Graphic drivers, Wine be mentioned if applicable , and apart from that nothing else but Updated system.

Comment: It largely depends on WHAT game.

Comment: Plus, your Hardware specifications

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you installed the driver for your videocard with `additional hardware` you are getting the best graphics performance you can.

[image]

You get some extra software where you can tweak settings (for amd/ati is it called AMD/ATI Catalyst:

[image]

and for nVidia:

[image]

<sub>please insert better image if available</sub>

It is important to note that it depends on what game you are talking. If it is native you probably need to depend on the ingame settings. If it is a game that you play with wine every game tends to have specific settings in wine that improve quality or speed but there are so many options it is impossible to tell. You need to rely on [wineHQ](http://www.winehq.org/) for those games. And this, looks to me, beyond AU and more suited for wine forums.

Regnum Online (plays natively) has several ingame settings to improve quality over performance. Eternal Lands plays without problems at full quality.
A gane like Rose Online (wine) does not work well with my videocard and I need to keep it on lowest graphics settings. I got lots of black images (mainly floor) if I play with high perfomance.

All in all: Ubuntu is not really suited to play Windows games. [But Valve is working in it](http://blogs.valvesoftware.com/linux/steamd-penguins/) ;)

Answer (score 2):

1. Graphic card driver
2. Sometimes for wine app's there are patches improving performance
3. Preload package
4. Update your software regularly
5. Last resort thing: dual-boot ubuntu with windows
6. Change vm.swappiness to 10 in **/etc/sysctl.conf** (default 60)